# Unable to detect cause of memory leak

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

In this function i have a memory leak on two locations according to Xcode's Instrument leak tool.

I don't have ARC enabled and wont be able to activate it, so i have to manage this in another way.

```
+(NSArray *)changePolygonFrom:(NSArray *)polygon size:(float)size{

    int nmrOfPoints = [polygon count];
    double x[nmrOfPoints];
    double y[nmrOfPoints];
    for (int i = 0; i < nmrOfPoints; i++) {
        CGPoint p = [[polygon objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        x[i] = p.x;
        y[i] = p.y;
    }

    insetPolygon(x,y,nmrOfPoints,size);

    NSMutableArray *rPolygon = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:nmrOfPoints];
    for(int i = 0; i < nmrOfPoints; i++){
        CGPoint p = CGPointMake(x[i], y[i]);
        NSValue *val = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p];
        [rPolygon addObject:val];
    }

    return rPolygon;
}
```

This is where i call it

```
-(void)fixFuzArrays{
    if (fuzzFix) {
        largeFuzzPolygon = [Triangulation changePolygonFrom:normalPolygon size:(shortestDistance/2)];
        smallFuzzPolygon = [Triangulation changePolygonFrom:normalPolygon size:(shortestDistance/6)];
    }else{
        largeFuzzPolygon = [Triangulation changePolygonFrom:normalPolygon size:-(shortestDistance/2)];
        smallFuzzPolygon = [Triangulation changePolygonFrom:normalPolygon size:-(shortestDistance/6)];
    }
}
```

If i use Auto release on the rPolygon i get a BAD_ACCESS on the objects iFrame and oFrame witch are the returned products of the previous function

```
-(void)drawAreaFuzzWithOuterFrame:(NSArray *)oFrame andInnerFrame:(NSArray *)iFrame withColor:(ccColor4B)c{
    for(int i = 0; i < [oFrame count]; i++){

        CGPoint oP1 = [[oFrame objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint iP1 = [[iFrame objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];

        CGPoint oP2;
        CGPoint iP2;

        if(i == [oFrame count]-1){
            oP2 = [[oFrame objectAtIndex:0]   CGPointValue];
            iP2 = [[iFrame objectAtIndex:0]   CGPointValue];
        }else{
            oP2 = [[oFrame objectAtIndex:i+1]   CGPointValue];
            iP2 = [[iFrame objectAtIndex:i+1]   CGPointValue];
        }

        GLfloat vertices[] = {
            oP1.x,oP1.y,
            oP2.x,oP2.y,
            iP1.x,iP1.y,
            iP2.x,iP2.y,
        };

        GLubyte colors[] = {
            c.r,c.g,c.b,c.a,
            c.r,c.g,c.b,c.a,
            c.r,c.g,c.b,0,
            c.r,c.g,c.b,0,
        };

        BEdrawGLShapeWithVertices(vertices, colors);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to autorelease the array before returning it and then retain the array in the method that is receiving it

add `autorelease` to `NSMutableArray`

```
NSMutableArray *rPolygon = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:nmrOfPoints] autorelease];
```

and then put retain on the method that use your function but you will have to release it later

```
NSArray *myArray = [[MyClass changePolygonFrom:array size:size] retain];
```

Don't forget to release `myArray` later

Comment: Thank you sir! i didn't event think about retain. but that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark the NSMutableArray as autorelease:

```
NSMutableArray *rPolygon = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:nmrOfPoints] autorelease];
```

If you don't do it, you are creating it, retaining it, and then returning it. It's never released.

Comment: That makes it crash later when im using the received array

Answer (score 0):

You forgot an autorelease while declaring *rPolygon*:

```
NSMutableArray *rPolygon = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:nmrOfPoints] autorelease];
```

**EDIT**
It seems that you are not retained the result of the `+(NSArray *)changePolygonFrom:(NSArray *)polygon size:(float)size` method.

Try to change your code retaining `largeFuzzPolygon` and `smallFuzzPolygon` (remember to release them in the dealloc method too):

```
-(void)fixFuzArrays{
    [largeFuzzPolygon release];
    [smallFuzzPolygon release];

    if (fuzzFix) {
        largeFuzzPolygon = [[Triangulation changePolygonFrom:normalPolygon size:(shortestDistance/2)] retain];
        smallFuzzPolygon = [[Triangulation changePolygonFrom:normalPolygon size:(shortestDistance/6)] retain];
    }else{
        largeFuzzPolygon = [[Triangulation changePolygonFrom:normalPolygon size:-(shortestDistance/2)] retain];
        smallFuzzPolygon = [[Triangulation changePolygonFrom:normalPolygon size:-(shortestDistance/6)] retain];
    }
}
```

or better I suggest you to **synthesize** them and use this code:

```
-(void)fixFuzArrays{
    if (fuzzFix) {
        self.largeFuzzPolygon = [[Triangulation changePolygonFrom:normalPolygon size:(shortestDistance/2)] retain];
        self.smallFuzzPolygon = [[Triangulation changePolygonFrom:normalPolygon size:(shortestDistance/6)] retain];
    }else{
        self.largeFuzzPolygon = [[Triangulation changePolygonFrom:normalPolygon size:-(shortestDistance/2)] retain];
        self.smallFuzzPolygon = [[Triangulation changePolygonFrom:normalPolygon size:-(shortestDistance/6)] retain];
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes it crash later when im using the received array

Comment: So you have a problem in another part of the code: can you post it?

Comment: As Marco said, that code I put is fine, your problem is in other part

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I don't see any call to the "changePolygonFrom" method. I assume that with that method you are createing an array and you use it later. Can you post the code where the "changePolygonFrom" method is used?